# PowerBI real time data without Stream Analytics

Tags: powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

How can I add live data to a PowerBI dashboard when I'm not using Azure Stream Analytics to passthrough messages? The refresh rates by default do not seem to support this.

Comment: You can use Direct Query Dashboard to connect to database, it's always live data

Comment: @CuongLe that's a good point. If this person is not looking for a real-time animating tile then connecting to a Direct Connect source may be all they need. http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/9/4/direct-connect-options-in-power-bi-for-live-querying-of-a-data-source

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The alternative for Stream Analytics would be to use the PowerBI API's to add row to a dataset.

Take a look at this [sample to get started](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/tree/master/samples/consoleapp/getting-started-for-dotnet)

Note: In the Free tier you can update 10k rows per hour.

Answer (score 0):

Stream Analytics output to Power BI is just a layer on top of this [Add Rows Power BI REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203561.aspx) plus a few related APIs like creating a dataset. You could do that yourself in your own code without Stream Analytics as shown in these [samples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203554.aspx). This still achieves the real-time animating tiles in Power BI.

Answer (score -1):

Only when you use Azure stream analytics, your Power BI dashboard is auto-refresh